# Polling in React-Native using class components

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native, polling

1. Periodically (every 10seconds) poll for new posts from this API
   https://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search_by_date?tags=story&page=0 via a GET
   request.
2. New posts fetched after 10 seconds will be added to old posts.
3. Increase page count in each subsequent request.
4. Implement pagination when the list is scrolled.
5. The pagination and periodic request both should work manually exclusive i.e for
   each request page number will be increased. Requests with the same page
   number should never be made.
6. Display the title, URL, created_at, and author of each post in a table.
7. Upon selecting a row in the table, a model should appear containing the raw
   JSON data of the post.
8. Support the ability to filter by created_at and title.
9. Support the ability to search the table by title, URL, and author name.

What I have Done for that

class MainPostPoll extends Component<any, any> {
constructor(props: any) {
super(props)
this.state = {
loading: false,
fromFetch: false,
fromAxios: false,
axiosData: [],
}
}

goForAxios = () => {
this.setState({
loading: true,
})
axios
.get('https://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search_by_date?tags=story&page=0')
.then((response) => {
console.log('getting data from axios', response.data)

```
    this.setState({
      loading: false,
      axiosData: response.data.hits,
    })
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error)
  })
```

}

renderItem = (item: any) => {
return (

{item.item.title}
{item.item.url}
{item.item.created_at}
{item.item.author}

)
}

render() {
return (

```
  <View>
    <View style={{ margin: 18 }}>
      <TouchableOpacity style={{}} onPress={this.goForAxios}>
        <Text>PostPoll</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
   
    <FlatList
      data={this.state.axiosData}
      renderItem={(item) => this.renderItem(item)}
      keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
    />
  </View>
)
```

}
}

Comment: Hey Shubham, I would recommend that you use Functional components & hooks in react. Check https://beta.reactjs.org/ to learn about them. Hooks make your code lean and clean :)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.